# Aerospike Query read all the records with Bin1 == Bin2

Tags: node.js, aerospike

I have a nodejs and aerospike set up. I want to know how run a query where `Bin1 == Bin2`.

In SQL

```
SELECT * FROM [test]t where t.EmployeeId == t.shipperid
```

Can it be done ? I can always query all the values from `test` set and filter it in nodejs. However I think it will be highly inefficient. Please let me know if there is an aerospike way to doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extra bin, `"equal_ids"`, which is set to true when the IDs are equal. This bin is to have a secondary index. Then, you can do a secondary index query for `equal_ids==true`

Comment: yea I could do that, however the real problem here is that today I'm checking for Bin1 == Bin 2 tom there would be a requirement where I need to check for Bin2 == Bin 3(over and above the prev check ?). I would  end up adding/updating a boolean value to all the existing records in the database again. IMHO Works as a quick solution or for a particular use case. Doesn't work on the long run.

Comment: IMO That's probably the way to do it in the NoSQL world. You need to know all the queries you'll be making up front and then design a compatible schema for quick access. That includes data duplication/redundancy, including the "extra" boolean values you mention. If your queries are varied/unpredictable, perhaps an SQL solution would work better. Perhaps someone more reputable can chime in.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported through the existing [query](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/query.html) predicates, but you can express this as a [stream UDF](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/developing_stream_udfs.html).

```
local function bin_match_filter(bin1, bin2)
  return function(rec)
    if rec[bin1] and rec[bin2] and
       (type(rec[bin1]) == type(rec[bin2])) and
       rec[bin1] == rec[bin2] then
      return true
    end
    return false
  end
end

local function map_record(rec)
  local ret = map()
  for i, bin_name in ipairs(record.bin_names(rec)) do
    ret[bin_name] = rec[bin_name]
  end
  return ret
end

function check_bins_match(stream, bin1, bin2)
  return stream : filter(bin_match_filter(bin1, bin2)) : map(map_record)
end
```

You can now run the records matched by a [secondary index](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/secondary-index.html) query, or a scan through this stream UDF.